# how to check for BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending when my thread has called another?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, sharppcap, pcap.net

How should I check for a CancellationPending within a BackgroundWorker DoWork method, when within this method I call off to a Pcap.Net packet capture routine, which responses via a callback.  The two options I can think of is:

a) write a loop at the bottom of the DoWork method to continually check for CancellationPending

b) put the check in the callback method I wrote which Pcap.Net will call back into - but no doubt the potential issue here is the cancellation can't work then until another patch match occurs and there is a callback

suggestions?

```
public class MainClass {
       private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       {
            var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            _packetCapturer = new PacketCapturer();
        }

}

    public class PacketCapturer

      public PacketCapturer() {
         // Start Capture Here
         // Opens PacketCommunicator
         // communicator.ReceivePackets(0, PacketCapturerCallback);

      }

      private static void PacketCapturerCallback(Packet packet) {
         // Deal with returned packet

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a BGW if you use the OnPacketArrival event.  Makes it easy to stop, just call StopCapture().

The other way, GetNextPacket() *does* need a BGW.  You have to open the device with a read timeout that short enough so you can see the CancellationPending flag quick enough.  You'll also have to deal with the overhead of getting it displayed on your UI, ReportProgress is *not* cheap.  And freezes the UI when you call it more often than ~1000 times per second.

**I wonder if we're talking about the same library...**

Comment: so I was going to aggregate packet responses into 1 second summaries, only calculate a summary figure for the 1 second period, and then once per second feed this back to the UI.  I thought that offloading this aggregation to a backgroundworker from the UI thread would be a good thing to do

Comment: Sounds okay.  Use GetNextPacket with the timeout, the event will be raised on the wrong thread.  Getting the 1 second intervals will be a wee bit tricky.

Comment: actually it is http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/ library (not sharppcap) in fact sorry

Comment: actually (seriously) is there a real reason you would recommend Sharppcap?  I found that with pcap.net I could get access down to the IP / TCP packet properties more easily and via intelisense than with SharpPcap.  I'm still not sure which is the most solid or most used.

Comment: @Greg I'm not sure if that's the case anymore. Take a look @ http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx. It's a one step process to take a captured packet event handler and parse it for the specific header needed. A lot of work has been done over the past year to make this process easier and more intuitive to the users.

Comment: @Greg SharpPcap is also geared more toward performance packet capturing (it has been proven to capture at rates approaching 3gb/s). IE, SharpPcap is designed only to be a winpcap/libpcap wrapper. All of the additional parser code is contained in the separate Packet.Net library. The split was intentional because not all users who capture packets (IE protocol designers) need the excess cruft of a packet parsing framework. AFAIK, Pcap.Net lumps everything (wrapper/parsing) all together into one package.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with delaying the cancellation until the next patch match; this is how BackgroundWorkers are supposed to work.